# Assigning an Include to a string variable PHP

Tags: php, include

I have template files which I need to further process so would like to assign it to a string variable using an include not using file_get_contents. The reason for this is because the final output is buffered through ob and contains php which needs to execute. If I use file_get_contents it wont execute. Problem is if I use $output = include 'file.php' it prints output without assigning.

Comment: Where's the output buffering - the included script or the main script?

Comment: Add another layer of output buffering, and use `ob_get_clean()`

Comment: the main script call a class to set up the page and process the templates. In the main page it call this class, processes output and I use ob_start() //$template = ob_get_contents(); 
//ob_clean(); 

//$registry->getObject('template')->parseOutput();
//$template = $registry->getObject('template')->getPage()->getContentToPrint();

//$template = str_replace(array("\r\n","\n","\r"),'',$template);

//echo $template;

//ob_end_flush();

Comment: $template = ob_get_contents(); 
ob_clean(); 
$registry->getObject('template')->parseOutput();
$template = $registry->getObject('template')->getPage()->getContentToPrint();

$template = str_replace(array("\r\n","\n","\r"),'',$template);

echo $template;

ob_end_flush(); sorry I had lines commented for testing

Comment: I believe the answer below by `CORRUPT` is exactly what you want, but just to note, if you use a url in `file_get_contents()` instead of a filepath, the php should execute.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
ob_start();

include 'file.php';

$output = ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: That was the method I was using before I decided to do the processing in a class. Reason I decided to do the class was to better organize, process and store the templates. However I did not know that using a URL instead of path for file_get_contents would allow the php to execute. Thanks for the tip.